# MUI makeStyles isn't working on the Card component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components, makestyles

I have this component called `Product` which is based off [this](https://mui.com/components/cards/#primary-action) example. Here is my component:

`Product.tsx`:

```
import useStyles from './useStyles'

const Product: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.secondaryBorder}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5">
            This is my title
          </Typography>

          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            This is my body
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

`useStyles.ts`:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  secondaryBorder: {
    border: '2px solid blue',
  },
  flex: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
});
```

The problem is that the `Card` component does not have the `secondaryBorder` i.e. it does not have a blue border around it. So what is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your error in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-makestyles-card-with-border-2fuec?file=/src/Product.tsx) with no luck. Maybe, you have a typo somewhere because I think that code should work nicely. Check the imports, maybe you are not importing the useStyles const correctly

Comment: It is because I removed the import statement for `useStyles` for this question. It should work now.